# How to pass the -encoding parameter to the java compiler from within VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javac

My Java program's source files are encoded in UTF-8. According to the [documentation of the Java compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> If **-encoding** is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

I'm on Windows where the default encoding is cp 850, so I have to add `-encoding UTF-8` to javac in order to avoid incorrect accented characters in the console output of my program. The program is displayed fine when I compile it from command-line this way.

However I can't find how to pass this parameter to the Java compiler from within VS Code. I have the Java Extension Pack installed. It provides the launch configuration parameter `"args"` which passes arguments to the program itself, but there's nothing in the documentation about how to pass parameters to the compiler. I would like this to be done automatically when I press "Run". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

open the settings of code-runner,add the following line:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
"java": "cd $dir && javac -encoding UTF-8 $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```